# Покрытие для лампы в вагоне

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что заключает лампу в метро? Корпус или абажур?

Answer (score 3):

*Корпус* лампы ( в форме колбы, свечи, трубки) - принадлежность самой лампы. Наружный стеклянный рассеиватель у отдельных ламп обычно называют **плафоном**. Абажур - обычно тканевый колпак или цилиндр с пониженной светопроницаемостью, защищающий глаза от боковой засветки путём частичного экранирования. Из рисунка не совсем ясно, открытые здесь трубки (корпуса светильников) или они закрыты общим **рассеивателем** (прозрачным *кожухом*).